# Assigning templates in Gatsbyjs regardless of "same folder" paradigm

Tags: reactjs, react-router, gatsby

Is it possible to assign templates to pages (_template.js) in Gatsbyjs some other way than having them reside in the same folder as the pages being transformed by them? I can imagine wanting to use common templates across folders, but not necessarily always the same templates. I'd rather just have a "templates" folder and have them assigned in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0 with the new [programmatic routes](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/421) where you'll be able to directly set the "layout" (not using template name anymore as it was wrong) for routes. In 0.x you're a bit stuck. With sufficient effort you could hack something like this into place but it'd probably mean forking Gatsby somewhat.